# Fill Dataset From DataGrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

When a Dataset is Binded with a Datagrid, Which property holds that Dataset;

if it is ; then can it return the Dataset of DataGrid ?

i don't think there is any property which returns the dataset from datagrid  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the datagrid in the xaml as:

```
    <Grid>
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,32,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
   </Grid>
```

and you are assigning the dataset to the datagrid like:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].AsDataView();
```

Then you can do the following:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataView)dataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();
DataSet dsNew = new DataSet();
dsNew.Tables.Add(dt);
```

You `dsNew` will hold the table from the datagrid.